# How would we symbolize the following English sentence logically?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Only a knight can marry my daughter. [ K(x): x is a knight; M(x, y): x can marry
y; d: my daughter ]

I have tried to create some equivalences and identities, but none of them seem to be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$M(x, d) \implies K(x)$.

If $x$ marries $d$ then $x$ is a Knight.

You can throw in some quantifiers
if it will make you feel better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with set notation:

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the set of the population, and let $\mathbb{K}$ be the set of knights and $\mathbb{M}$ be the set of those eligible to marry the daughter be subsets of $\mathbb{P}$

Then $\mathbb{M} \subseteq \mathbb{K}$

Answer (score 0):

"Only a knight can marry my daughter."
$\equiv$
"If anything can marry my daughter, then it is a knight."